# Using Nginx to serve a static files in a subdirectory

Tags: nginx, static, subdirectory

I currently have a bunch of working static files at the domain name khairulslt.me (from NameCheap). Recently, I've tried setting up a subdomain (khairulslt.me/RGBGame) as seen in the code below; However, I keep getting 404 errors. What am i missing out?

```
server {
  listen 80;

  index circles.html;
  server_name khairulslt.me www.khairulslt.me;

  location / {
  root /var/www/khairulslt.me;
  add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy- 
  revalidate, max-age=0';
  expires off;
  }

  location /RGBGame {
  alias /var/www/RGBGame/colorGame.html;
  index colorGame.html;
  }
}
```

PS: I want to serve the new files as a working web app under the same Digital Ocean droplet that I'm using for the circles app.

Comment: Check your access.log and you will see where your request is going in file system

Comment: 59.189.202.117 - - [07/Jun/2018:13:39:06 +0800] "GET /RGBGame HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
Yeah I got that, not sure where to start with that though unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it.
Needed to change this block of code here:

```
location /RGBGame {
root /var/www/khairulslt.me;
index colorGame.html;
try_files $uri $uri/ /var/www/RGBGame/colorGame.html?q=$uri&$args;
autoindex off;
}
```

Will leave my final configuration here in case it helps anyone:

```
server {

  server_name khairulslt.me www.khairulslt.me;

  autoindex off;
  location / {
    root /var/www/khairulslt.me;
    index circles.html;
  }


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/khairulslt.me/fullchain.pem; # managed by 
Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/khairulslt.me/privkey.pem; # managed 
by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

location /RGBGame {
    root /var/www/khairulslt.me/RGBGame;
    index colorGame.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /var/www/RGBGame/colorGame.html?q=$uri&$args;
    autoindex off;
  }

location /robots.txt { return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"; 
  }

}

 server {
if ($host = www.khairulslt.me) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot


if ($host = khairulslt.me) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name khairulslt.me www.khairulslt.me;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

What this config does:

1) Serve static files, Web App #1, aka bunch of html/css/js files) at the URL khairulslt.me

2) Serve second set of static files, Web App #2, aka bunch of html/css/js files) at the URL khairulslt.me/RGBGame

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide a path to the file, but to the directory in your alias directive.

So simply use:

```
location /RGBGame/ { 
    alias /var/www/RGBGame/; 
    index colorGame.html; 
}
```

Comment: Have tried that but still returns error 404 : |
Do u know if there are any other instructions i need to perform to set up a subdirectory? Like using Express to set a route or something? Completely new to this sorry for the newbie questions!

Comment: Make sure you are editting the right file. Do you have ssl??

Try checking "/sites-available/default" this may be where you need to edit.

Answer (score 1):

You alias seems to be pointing to a file `colorGame.html` give a try to this:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name khairulslt.me www.khairulslt.me;


  location /RGBGame/ {
     alias /var/www/RGBGame/;
  }
}
```

When using `alias` a request to `://khairulslt.me/RGBGame/file.foo` will serve files from:

```
/var/www/RGBGame/file.foo
```

You could use `root` for example (append the location to the path):

```
  location /RGBGame/ {
     root /var/www/khairulslt.me/;
  }
```

In this case, requests to `://khairulslt.me/RGBGame/file.foo` will serve files from:

```
/var/www/khairulslt.me/RGBGame/file.foo
```

Comment: thanks! have tried both alias and root variants and still 404; I Also cant remove index circles.html; in the 3rd line, otherwise khairulslt.me will not load in the browser

Comment: @sgeza do you have files (images) on the defined paths?

Comment: yeap i do, css/js/html files on the defined paths, i never had to define "running them on my main khairulslt.me to get that one working though